# get_categories for Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a Custom Post Type, 'ioni_codex'
I am using built-in Wordpress category as taxonomy

I want to list all categories used by 'ioni_codex'.

I assume that this code will do the trick:

```
$myargs = array (
    'type' => 'ioni_codex'
); 
$categories = get_categories( $myargs );
```

However instead I see the list of *all categories* not the categories assigned to by 'ioni_codex'.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`get_categories()` does not accept `post_type` as an argument, use `taxonomy` instead and refer to the taxonomy by the name you gave it when registering it. Here is a link to the codex which can explain it in more detail -  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories.

Comment: I can use 'type', it still does not procue the desired result.

I looked into get_terms and it appears that it does not account for post_type whatsoever.
What I need is to list categories in which the 'ioni_codex'appears. Instead it lists me all categories

Comment: custom post types don't have categories.

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned you are using the default WordPress categories in your custom post type (CPT). To get the categories used only for your CPT you would need to create a separate taxonomy and register it with your CPT. Here is a link to Custon Taxonomy Codex Page : http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies#Custom_Taxonomies

Comment: I got half of answer in a sister project:

Answer (score 1):

Instead of type you have to set post_type , by default get_categories try to hide empty categories , if you want display it all add hide_empty property set to false

```
 get_categories(array(
    'post_type' => 'ioni_codex',
    'hide_empty' => false,
   ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

While quick reading @ioni's answer; it looks like it would give you a proper result it will most likely be pretty slow as it goes through every post and then looks for all terms that belong to each post individually. This will easily result in thousands of SQL queries.

My recommendation is to use a single query to get the IDs of all terms that belong to a post type. Then use those ids to filter `get_terms()`.

**MySQL query:**

```sql
SELECT
    wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
FROM
    wp_term_relationships
LEFT JOIN wp_posts ON wp_term_relationships.object_id = wp_posts.ID
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE
    wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'ioni_codex'
GROUP BY
    term_id
```

**PHP function:**

```php
<?php

function ioni_get_terms_by_post_type( $taxonomy = 'category', $post_type = 'post', $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $sql = $wpdb->prepare(
        "
            SELECT
                {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_id
            FROM
                {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts ON {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id = {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy ON {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
            WHERE
                {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy = '%s'
            AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = '%s'
            GROUP BY
                term_id
        ",
        $taxonomy,
        $post_type,
    );
    $term_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
    
    if ( empty( $term_ids ) ) {
        return array();
    }

    // custom code to allow for exclude to work
    if ( ! empty( $args['exclude'] ) ) {
        // allow exclude to be either a string or array
        $exclude = is_string(  $args['exclude'] ) ? (array) $args['exclude'] : $args['exclude'];
        
        // filter $term_ids with array from $args['exclude']
        $term_ids = array_filter( $term_ids, function( $term_id ) use ( $exclude ) {
            return ! in_array( $term_id, $exclude );
        } );
    }

    $args = wp_parse_args(
        $args,
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'include' => $term_ids,
        ),
    );

    return get_terms( $args );
}
```

**Usage:**

```php
<?php

$categories = ioni_get_terms_by_post_type( 'category', 'ioni_codex' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer at a sister project:
Bainternet♦ has re-written get_terms() function to provide for the post_type

Please refer to his solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14331/get-terms-by-taxonomy-and-post-type) or just copy and past from below:

```
/* get terms limited to post type 
 @ $taxonomies - (string|array) (required) The taxonomies to retrieve terms from. 
 @ $args  -  (string|array) all Possible Arguments of get_terms http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms
 @ $post_type - (string|array) of post types to limit the terms to
 @ $fields - (string) What to return (default all) accepts ID,name,all,get_terms. 
 if you want to use get_terms arguments then $fields must be set to 'get_terms'
*/
function get_terms_by_post_type($taxonomies,$args,$post_type,$fields = 'all'){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => (array)$post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $terms = array();
    while ($the_query->have_posts()){
        $the_query->the_post();
        $curent_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy);
        foreach ($curent_terms as $t){
          //avoid duplicates
            if (!in_array($t,$terms)){
                $terms[] = $c;
            }
        }
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    //return array of term objects
    if ($fields == "all")
        return $terms;
    //return array of term ID's
    if ($fields == "ID"){
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            $re[] = $t->term_id;
        }
        return $re;
    }
    //return array of term names
    if ($fields == "name"){
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            $re[] = $t->name;
        }
        return $re;
    }
    // get terms with get_terms arguments
    if ($fields == "get_terms"){
        $terms2 = get_terms( $taxonomies, $args );
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            if (in_array($t,$terms2)){
                $re[] = $t;
            }
        }
        return $re;
    }
}
```